# Compiling three files fortran 77 "Line too long"

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran77, g77

I'm trying to compile three files with g77. 
One of the files, a subroutine for the main file, returns

```
Jades-MacBook-Pro:Jade jadecheclair$ g77 -c atmsetup.for 
Line too long as of (?) [info -f g77 M LEX]
```

I'm very new to fortran and couldn't find any explanation to this online. The other two files work and create .o files, and one of them (also a subroutine) looks exactly the same as this one.

Anyone knows what this means and how to fix it?

Since it doesn't let me know what line is causing trouble, I attach the code here:

```
      SUBROUTINE ATMSETUP(NLEVEL,Z,RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,TEMP,PRESS,DEN,XMU,
     & CH4,H2,XN2,AR,IPRINT)
C THIS IS THE NEW ONE WITH THE BWC EQ OF STATE
      PARAMETER (NMAX=201)
C THIS SUBROUTINE SETS UP THE INTITAL ATMOSPHERIC PROFILE FOR TITAN
C BASED ON THE LINDAL ET AL DATA.  THE ROUTINE STARTS WITH INPUTS
C INPUTS:  
C NLEVEL:   NUMBER OF ALTITUDE LEVELS, J=1 IS AT THE TOP
C Z         ALTITUDE GRID IN KM
C RHCH4     RELATIVE HUMIDITY OF METHANE AT Z=0.
C FH2       MIXING RATIO BY NUMBER OF H2
C FARGON    ARGON FLAG 0 = NO ARGON IN ATMSOPHERE 
C                     -Y = ADJUST AR TO GIVE MEAN WEIGHT=Y
C                     +X = MIXING RATIO OF ARGON = X
C OUTPUTS: AT EACH LEVEL (NOT LAYER AVERAGES)
C TEMP (K), PRESS(BARS), DEN(CM-3), XMU = MEAN MOLECUALR WEIGHT
C CH4, H2, XN2, AR ARE THE NUMBER MIXING RATIOS OF THE GASES
C INTERNAL VARIABLES
C TLINAL, DLINAL, PLINAL : THE LINDAL INGRESS VALUES ON THE Z GRID
C
C NOTES: METHANE FOLLOWS CONSTANT MIXING RATIO UNLESS SATUARTION
C        VALUE IS LOWER.
C
      DIMENSION Z(NLEVEL),TEMP(NLEVEL),PRESS(NLEVEL),DEN(1),XMU(1) 
      DIMENSION CH4(1),H2(1),XN2(1),AR(1)

      DIMENSION TLINAL(NMAX),DLINAL(NMAX),PLINAL(NMAX)
C
C FIRST SET UP THE LINDAL PURE N2 VALUES
      CALL LINDAL(NLEVEL,Z,TLINAL,DLINAL,PLINAL)
C LOAD THE LINDAL VALUES INTO THE ARRAYS
      DO J=1,NLEVEL
      TEMP(J)= TLINAL(J)
      DEN(J)=  DLINAL(J)
      PRESS(J)=PLINAL(J)
      ENDDO
C
      DO 1000 ITS =1,20
C
C NOW COMPUTE THE MEAN MOLECULAR WEIGHT AT EACH LEVEL
C NOW SET UP THE MIXING RATIOS OF THE GASSES BASED ON SATURATION
C CURVE OF CH4 AND SPECIFIED MEAN MOLECULAR WEIGHT AND H2 CONSTANT
      CH4(NLEVEL)=PCH4(TEMP(NLEVEL))*RHCH4/PRESS(NLEVEL)
      DO 134 J=NLEVEL-1,1,-1
      CH4SAT=PCH4(TEMP(J))/PRESS(J)
      CH4(J)=AMIN1(CH4SAT,CH4(NLEVEL),CH4(J+1))
 134  CONTINUE
      DO 20 J=1,NLEVEL
      H2(J)=FH2  
      IF (FARGON .LT. 0.) THEN
C WE DECIDED TO KEEP CONSTANT MIXING RATIO = -FARGON
      AR(J)=(-FARGON-28.0134+25.8554*H2(J)+11.9708*CH4(J))/11.9346
      ELSE 
                    IF (FARGON .EQ. 0.) THEN
C                       WE DECIDED TO DROP THE ARGON...
                    AR(J)=0.0
                        ELSE
C                       ARGON GIVEN BY A CONSTANT MIXING RATIO
                            AR(J)=FARGON
                    ENDIF
      ENDIF
      XN2(J)=1.0 - H2(J) - CH4(J) -AR(J)
      XMU(J)=28.0134*XN2(J)+2.158*H2(J)+16.0426*CH4(J)+39.948*AR(J)
 20   CONTINUE
C AT THIS POINT WE HAVE THE TEMP, PRESS, DEN AND XMU VALUES.
C ADJUST THE DEN BY THE FACTOR DUE TO THE MEAN REFRACTIVITY
C NOW LETS INTERGRATE THE DENSITY WITH ALTITUDE TO GET THE PRESS
       SUMT=PLINAL(1)*6.02E23/10.
       SUMB=SUMT
      TLAST=TEMP(NLEVEL)
      DO J=2,NLEVEL
C DENSITY ADJUSTMENT BASED ON REFRACTIVITIES ... SEE NOTES
      DENF=294.1/(XN2(J)*294.1 + CH4(J)*410. + H2(J)*136. + AR(J)*277.8)
      DEN(J) = DLINAL(J)*DENF
C PERFORM THE INTEGRALS LISTED IN NOTES
C SUMT IS ACTUAL PRESSURE 
      ADEN=(DEN(J)-DEN(J-1))/ALOG(DEN(J)/DEN(J-1))
      SUMT=SUMT+(EFFG(Z(J))*ADEN)*( Z(J-1)-Z(J))*XMU(J)
      ADEN=(DLINAL(J)-DLINAL(J-1))/ALOG(DLINAL(J)/DLINAL(J-1))
      SUMB=SUMB+(EFFG(Z(J))*ADEN)*( Z(J-1)-Z(J))*28.01340
C
C NON IDEAL GAS CORRECTION IS 3.5% TIMES DT = 0.03% :NEGLECTED
      PRESS(J)=PLINAL(J)*SUMT/SUMB
      TEMP(J) =TLINAL(J)*(SUMT/SUMB)*(1./DENF)
C
      ENDDO
  30  CONTINUE
C
C HOW WELL WE DO ON CONVERGENCE
      DT= ABS(TEMP(NLEVEL)-TLAST)
      IF (DT .LT. 0.001) GO TO 1001
 1000 CONTINUE      
 1001 IF (IPRINT .LT. 0) RETURN
         WRITE (6,139)RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,DT
         DO 135 J=1,NLEVEL-1
         WRITE(6,140)J,Z(J),PRESS(J),DEN(J),TEMP(J),
     &          CH4(J)*PRESS(J)/PCH4(TEMP(J))
     &         ,CH4(J)*100.,XN2(J)*100.,H2(J)*100.,AR(J)*100.,XMU(J)
     &         ,(TEMP(J+1)-TEMP(J))/(Z(J+1)-Z(J))
  135    CONTINUE
         J=NLEVEL
         WRITE(6,140)J,Z(J),PRESS(J),DEN(J),TEMP(J),
     &    CH4(J)*PRESS(J)/PCH4(TEMP(J))
     &    ,CH4(J)*100.,XN2(J)*100.,H2(J)*100.,AR(J)*100.,XMU(J)
  139 FORMAT(///'   BACKGROUNG ATMOSPHERE AT LEVELS'/
     & ' SURFACE HUMIDITY OF CH4:',F5.3,'  H2 MIXING RATIO:',F6.4,
     & ' ARGON SETTING:',F8.4/'  FINAL CONVERGENCE ON TEMP:',F10.5
     &  '   LINDAL ET AL SCALING'/
     &' LVL ALTITUDE  P(BARS)  DEN(CM-3) TEMP RH-CH4'
     & , ' %CH4  %N2   %H2  %AR   MU   DT/DZ'  )
  140 FORMAT(1X,I3,F8.3,1P2E10.3,0PF7.2,F5.2,2F6.2,2F5.2,4F6.2)
C END INTITAL BACKGROUND ATMOSPHERE SETUP FOR TITAN
      RETURN
      END
```

Comment: What does the offending section of code look like?

Comment: It doesn't say anything more than this, I wish it would tell me a line number or a word that causes trouble but that's the only output I get :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fortran: line to long / append line - but with text at the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373342/fortran-line-to-long-append-line-but-with-text-at-the-end)

Comment: If the above indentation is exactly as you have it in the file, then there is an error on the second line: The `&` character **must** be the 6th character of that line (indicating that this is a continuation of the line before.)

Comment: Try adding -ffixed-line-length-132

Comment: @chw21 Doesn't change anything to put all the & comment one line further :/

Comment: @cup I tried "Jades-MacBook-Pro:Joseph jadecheclair$ g77 -ffixed-line-length-132 atmsetup.for 
Line too long as of (?) [info -f g77 M LEX]"
The same error pops up

Comment: Can you try compiling with gfortran or some other compiler produced in this century?

Comment: The program was written in 1987

Comment: So? Can you try compiling with gfortran or some other compiler produced in this century? If for nothing, then to have better error diagnostics.

Comment: I am voting to close the question as the problem cannot be reproduced. The code in the question can be compiled by gfortran. Provide more information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was visible by opening the file in vim. All the lines were together even though the program looked fine in Xcode.

Just opened the file in textedit and reformatted it. Then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code into a text editor and looked at it.  Your second line, a continuation of the SUBROUTINE statement on line 1 appears to have it's line continuation in the wrong column.  It should be column 6.

-Eric

Comment: Unfortunately that was just a mistake of putting 4 spaces for the sake of stack overflow :/

Comment: I'm not seeing anything else obviously wrong.  I'd try deleting or commenting out lines and see what makes the error go away.